# Momentum space integrals in dimensional regularization

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, dimensional-regularization

I am trying to go through some derivations in this paper (http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.3170). I am unsure about how they got from eq 56 to eq 57.

Specifically the step is from 
$$i\int \frac{d^dq}{(2\pi)^{d-2}} \theta(q_0)\delta(q^2)\theta(p_0-q_0)\delta((q-p)^2)$$$$ = i\frac{\Gamma(1+\epsilon)\Gamma^2(1-\epsilon)}{(4\pi)^{2-\epsilon}\Gamma(1-2\epsilon)}\frac{(|p^2|)^{-\epsilon}}{\epsilon(1-2\epsilon)}2\sin(\pi\epsilon)\theta(p^2)\theta(p_0).$$

I know they are using dimensional regularization in $d = 4-2\epsilon$ but I’m not sure about how to go about and tackle this integral.

I know in textbook 1-loop QFT calculations there are some propagators and usually one uses the Feynman parameterization to get them all in a common factor and then use a change of variables in the momenta. Then one uses Wick rotation to get it into Euclidean space in which the angular components are just the surface area of a $d$ dimensional sphere and then the radial integral involves the $\Gamma$ function. However here there are no propagators and I'm not sure how to proceed.

I am also confused at how they get from eq 41 to eq 42.
$$\int \frac{d^dq}{(2\pi)^{d-2}} \delta_+(q^2)\frac{1}{2qk+k^2+i0c(k)}$$$$ = -\frac{c_{\Gamma}}{2\cos(\pi\epsilon)}\frac{1}{\epsilon(1-2\epsilon)}\left[\frac{k^2}{k_0}-i0k^2c(k)\right]^{-\epsilon}[k_0-i0k^2c(k)]^{-\epsilon}.$$

Which probably is a similar calculation as the first. Though in this case I’m unsure of how to work the Feynman parameterization.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to get eqn 55 from eqn 52? Because solving for eqn 56 needs the same procedure.

Comment: No I couldn't get that either. Yes, I realize it's essentially the same calculation. Does the calculation have something to do with integrating the angular component? I'm not sure how to parameterize $q\cdot p$ in $d$ dimensions. Can it still be written as $|q||p|\cos(\theta)$? Then I wouldn't know which spherical angle $\theta$ to consider.